# Defining Form into variable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, variables

If you want to insert a variable Form2, I use this ..

```
Dim Variable As New Form2
```

But if I have the same functions with names in two forms, I'll do it using if.

```
if 1 = 1 Then
     Dim Variable As New Form2
Else
     Dim Variable As New Form3
End If
```

That's perfectly fine, but if I start using this variable in the code below, an error occurs if I use without conditions, everything is fine, use when the condition seemed to understand what to do.

```
Variable.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

> Object reference not set to instance of an object

Comment: Your creating a locally scoped variable and no longer setting the value of your global `Variable` Take the `dim` out, ie: `Variable= New Form3()`

Comment: You'd be better off having a form2 and form3 variable already and simply using the one you want based on the condition.  An `If` statement creates a new block scope - anything declared inside it will only exist there.

Comment: ...the reason for this is to avoid your next question *how can I tell whether variable is Form2 or Form3?*

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variable first and then assign it to a particular type:

```
Dim Variable As Form = Nothing
If 1 = 1 Then
   Variable = New Form2()
Else
   Variable = New Form3()
End If
```

But usually you would do this in an object oriented approach by each form implementing a common interface.

You can then do this:

```
Dim Variable As IForm
If 1 = 1 Then
   Variable = New Form2() 'Form2 implements IForm
Else
   Variable = New Form3() 'Form3 implements IForm
End If
```